# How to say correctly the root directory is "auto filling"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

This is related to a UNIX system where files are stored and root system is getting full and system hung. I am trying to express that the reason for this is that root directory is "auto filling". There is some script or task that is automatically generating files to the root directory so it is getting full. It is not human intervention that is making this happen.

Could you please advise if saying "the root directory is auto filling" is the best suitable way expressing this?

I have the feeling there is a better way.

Comment: Could you please add a bit more detail about why you have a “feeling there is a better way”? Otherwise, this looks like a request for proofreading, which is expressly off-topic on ELL.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to express?

Comment: Please specify what do you want to express. I am quite sure there is a better way to say that because this sentence is not meaningful.

Comment: This is related to unix system. Where files are stored and root system is getting full and system hung. I am trying to express that the reason for this is that root directory is auto filling. There is some script or task that is automatically generated files to root directory so it is getting full. It is not human intervention that is making this happen.

Comment: Your grammar is fine but you're using an incorrect word.  "Auto-" means that the thing is doing it to itself.  The root directory is not filling itself up, something else is filling it up, so *auto* is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If we say

> The root directory is filling up with files.

or

> The root directory is getting filled up with files.

we omit a reference to that which is creating the files, and refer only to the fact that files are accumulating there.

The root directory is not self-populating, however, in the same way that you are not self-wetting here:

> It is raining heavily and he is getting wet.

P.S. If you wish to express the idea that there are very many files being created in a very short time, so many files that it would be impossible for a person to have created them "by hand", and a script or daemon process must be responsible:

> The root directory is getting completely filled up with files *by some background process*.

just as we can say

> He is getting parched by the heat.
>
> He is getting totally drenched by the storm.

Comment: great answer thanks a lot :) that was what I were looking for

Answer (score 0):

> **auto filling**

would not be the best way to describe what is happening, since "***auto***" means self and the understanding is the root directory is filling itself, which is not possible.

If you are sysadmin you could post

> Would whoever is **filling up** the root directory, please stop!

the action of **filling up** is what you are concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

You could also express that idea with this sentence:

> The root directory is getting rapidly cluttered with lots of auto-generated files.